# matlab cursor.data being case sentive

Tags: sql, matlab, db2, fetch

I have this huge code which I use it to retrieve data from sql and db2.

```
cur=exec(conn,sql);

cur=fetch(cur);

cur = cur.data;
```

Each time when it is at cur.data. It trows an error. Is there any way to make matlab read cur.data instead of cur.Data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why can't you change the code to `cur.Data`?

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB variables are case sensitive. You should make sure that whatever is inside `cur` has always the same name.

Try to avoid having case-variation at all costs.

---

However, if its not in your hands, then I suggest doing

```
if isfield(cur,'data')
   cur=cur.data;
else if isfield(cur,'Data')
       cur=cur.Data;
     else
        error('No data found' )
     end
end
```